# how to set value in TextInput using UseRef React hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to set value in text input using the UseRef hook.

```
inputEl.current.value = "hello"
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
let textInput = React.useRef(null);
const [text, setText] = React.useState('');

<TextInput
     ref={(input) => textInput = input}
     value={text}
     placeholder='Enter here'
     onChangeText={(value) => setText(value)}
/>
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You're using a *state* the author specifically asks for changing the value using *useRef*.

Answer (score 0):

```
const val = inputEl.current.value = "hello"
<input type =  "text" value = {val} ref = {inputEl}/>
```

provide obtained value using value attribute